# Updating a cross - reference table with jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have the tables `Users`, `Factors`, and the cross reference `UserFactors`.

When i use the `store()` method on the cross referenced table, after setting both ids like this:

```
UserFactorsPOJO userFactors = new UserFactorsPOJO();
userFactors.setUserId(userId);
userFactors.setFactorId(FactorId);
userFactors.setValue(value);
UserFactorsRecord userFactRec = create.newRecord(UserFactors.USER_FACTORS, userFactors);
userFactRec.store();
```

Jooq attempts to insert a record, obviously since i'm setting the ids to the POJO and storing it. I get a "`Unique index or primary key violation`" error.

How do i retrieve the row i want by using the two ids, and then update that row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really updating a single value for a single ID, you shouldn't use jOOQ's [`UpdatableRecord`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdatableRecord.html) for the task to avoid issuing two queries. The simplest solution is this:

```
create.update(USER_FACTORS)
      .set(USER_FACTORS.VALUE, value)
      .where(USER_FACTORS.FACTOR_ID.eq(factorId))
      .execute();
```

See the manual's section about [the `UPDATE` statement](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/update-statement/). If you're planning on doing more sophisticated updates, you can also try using [jOOQ's `MERGE` statement support](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/merge-statement/), although in this example, I don't think you'll need `MERGE`

Comment: That makes sense.. I suppose in my case though, i should add a second condition in my where clause, for the 2nd foreign key :

`.where(USER_FACTORS.FACTOR_ID.eq(factorId).and(UserFactors.USER_FACTORS.USER_ID.eq(userId))`

Answer (score 1):

This is the best i could come up with.. Other suggestions are welcome.

```
    UserFactorsRecord userFactRec = create.fetchOne(UserFactors.USER_FACTORS, 
            UserFactors.USER_FACTORS.FACTOR_ID.eq(factorId).and(UserFactors.USER_FACTORS.USER_ID.eq(userId)));
    userFactRec.setValue(value);
    userFactRec.store();
```